# How can I group data but generate dynamic columns?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table of data which contains something like the below (but naturally far more rows).

edit : Think of each line below as being a distinct "purchase" of the quantity, valid for the date range.  I am trying to workout what the total quantity is, per CODE.

```
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
| CODE | START DATE | END DATE  | QUANTITY |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
| AAA  | 01-Dec-19  | 15-Dec-19 |      555 |
| BBB  | 01-Dec-19  | 15-Dec-19 |      666 |
| AAA  | 01-Dec-19  | 15-Jan-20 |      100 |
| BBB  | 01-Dec-19  | 15-Jan-20 |      111 |
| AAA  | 01-Dec-19  | 15-Feb-21 |      200 |
| BBB  | 01-Dec-19  | 15-Feb-21 |      222 |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

I am trying to write Python/Pandas code which will work out the total quantity, per code, per monthend. The output needs to look something like this.

So pre 01 Dec 2019, we had nothing on the books and hence zero totals.  But at the end of Dec 2019, we held a total of 100+200 of AAA and 111+222 of BBB.

However, at the end of Jan 2020, the 100 of AAA and the 111 of BBB had both "matured" and we were just left with 200 and 222 respectively.

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---+-----------+
| CODE | 30-Nov-19 | 31-Dec-19 | 31-Jan-20 | 28-Feb-20 | … | 28-Feb-21 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---+-----------+
| AAA  |         0 |       300 |       200 |       200 | … |         0 |
| BBB  |         0 |       333 |       222 |       222 | … |         0 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---+-----------+
```

Comment: when a row spans multiple months, how is `'QUANTITY'` to be split among them?  In other words: you haven't done an adequate job describing your problem.

Comment: Will add more details to help clarify, but think of each line as a separate "purchase" of that quantity,  active in that date range.

Comment: How will the data in the first table show up in the second result table? Where does the 555 and 666 appear in the result? Where does the 333 come from?

Comment: Have added a few more comments, please let me know if its clearer.  Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

- Define a list `dates` of the dates that you want as columns in the final result.
- Write a function `my_func` that takes a CODE group of the DF and `dates`.

  - `my_func` will return a Series (maybe it needs to be a 1-column DataFrame, don't remember) with the dates as index. For every date `d`, it filters the rows of the CODE group where `d` falls in between START and END DATE and adds up the quantities.
- Then you can `df.groupby('code').apply(my_func, dates).unstack()` which should lead to your desired result.

If you provide your example as Python code, someone might actually code an answer for you.